# Ruby Jekyll - Octopress cannot Rake generate with URI

Tags: ruby, octopress

Looks like I am having serious issues with Jekyll. Nothing worked so far and I still have

> jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  bad URI(is not URI?):
>   https://gist.githubusercontent.com/

I have had included this along the way into my source:

> Gist Method: The sample code below can used to pull out code from Gist
>   from Github
>
> ```
>  {% gist gist_id [filename] %}
> ```

I wanted to illustrate these as examples in my blog but ran into rake generate issues giving the aforementioned errors. I have had done my research and after having closed the other errors (not closing blockquotes, etc), this is something I cannot figure out on my own.

Comment: Cannot reproduce locally with octopress. Did you have some code on github ?

Comment: No. Since I cannot rake generate, I cannot push the changes made locally, but the suspectable line which I think possibly is casuing problems is this one:

`{% gist gist_id [filename] %}`

I have attached a screen for your ready references:

`http://s4.postimg.org/pg6bcn5x9/havehad.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a documentation string with placeholders.

```
{% gist gist_id [filename] %}
```

This string is parsed by Octopress Gist plugins and as the resulting url ( `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/raw/id/[filename]`) has a wrong pattern, an error is thrown.

If you want to print this documentation in a post you can do.

```
{% highlight liquid %}
{% raw %}{% gist gist_id [filename] %}{% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

For more infos about Octopress' Gist tag, see : http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/gist-tag/

Comment: That's a very precise answer. With some tweak (using pygments), I am able to get them working in highlighted mode.

    `{% highlight liquid %}

    {% raw %}

    {% gist gist_id [filename] %}

    {% endraw %}

    {% endhighlight %}`

Comment: Did I answered your question ?

Comment: So maybe you can approve it. Thank you.

Comment: I have had just approved it. Thank you a lot for the help.